# Using Regular Expressions to get bigrams into a dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I'm trying to work with RegEx to make a dictionary with keys that are the bigrams from a text file, and whose values are the number of occurrences of those bigrams in the text.

I've got this code that gets me the bigrams. It's not perfect, because bigrams should be like "hello, world" , "world, full" ""full, of" "of, wonderful" "wonderful, things", but in my print out the bigrams are ordered differently than that so I'm not sure if I did it right.

I am not sure how to correlate these RegEx phrases that get the bigrams to go into a dictionary with keys that are those bigrams and values that reflect their count throughout the original text file. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer

with open('/Users/adamstark/PycharmProjects/Computational_Methods_Course/Assignments/Final/Jules_Verne_From_the_Earth_to_Moon.txt') as file:
    txt1 = file.readlines()

# Getting bigrams
txt1 = [remove_string_special_characters(s) for s in txt1]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range = (2,2))
X1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(txt1)
features = (vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print("\n\nFeatures : \n", features)
print("\n\nX1 : \n", X1.toarray())
```

Comment: You never call `remove_string_special_characters` anywhere in this code.  Is there more you haven't shown us?  And you can delete the line `text1 = []`.  It is both a typo and unnecessary.

Comment: No this is everything I have. I'm not sure what steps to take next.

Comment: Your code works fine.  The set of bigrams are printed in alphabetical order, so they won't be in the order of the source material.  And you can delete the pre-processing function that you don't call; it appears the vectorizer is already doing all of that for you.

Comment: Thanks, I tidied it up to reflect what you've indicated and incorporated what Manial A showed me below, and you also mentioned, the absence of "remove_string_special_characters." Now I'm trying to resolve a Name Error: "name 'remove_string_special_characters' is not defined" and looking to get the bigrams formatted into the dictionary format described.